# Express login: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: node.js, jwt

Good day developers im trying to trigger a process of login for users in my app, generating a token for security reasons, but for some situation im receiving this error

```
(node:11088) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async 
function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11088) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

despite of allowing the user to log, but then the token although is  created isn't exposed on the login json i generated for app purposes checked  from my postman.

Lets say i do start the process first in my folder of token generator, after install jsonwebtoken package

```
jsonwebtoken generation folder

const jsonwebToken = require("jsonwebtoken");

const generateToken =async  (userId) => {
  return new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
    const tokenPayload = { userId };

    jsonwebToken.sign(
      tokenPayload,
      process.env.TOKEN_SECRET_WORD,
      {
        expiresIn: "12h",
      },
      (error, generatedToken) => {
        if (error) {
           reject("cant generate token");
        } else {
          resolve(generatedToken);
        }
      }
    );
  });
};
module.exports = { generateToken };
```

Once the process of generate the token is set , on my controller for the loginUser function , i set this

```
et User = require("../modelos/UserModel");

const { response } = require("express");

const cryptoPass = require("bcryptjs");

const { generateToken } = require("../jsonwebtoken/jsonWebTokenGenerator");//path to the json generator

const loginUser = async (request, response = response) => {
  const { userEmail, userPassword } = request.body;

  try {
    const userInDb = await User.findOne({ userEmail });

    if (!userInDb) {
      return response.status(400).json({
        ok: false,
        message: "Not user Found",
      });
    } 

    const passwordValid = await cryptoPass.compareSync(
      userPassword,
      userInDb.userPassword
    );

    if (!passwordValid) {
      return response.status(400).json({
        ok: false,
        message: "Error in Password",
      });
    }

    const tokenGenerated =  generateToken(userInDb.id);//generating the tooken in the process
                                                       //in order to add it to the user logged json
                                                       //once the response is ok(200)

    response.status(200).json({
      ok: true,
      message: "User Logged",
      tokenGenerated,//no token
    });
  } catch (error) {
      response.status(500).json({
      ok: false,
      message: "Some error happened in login",
    });
  }
};
module.exports = {
  loginUser,
};
```

But then despite of loggin the user , the token isn't brought in the response and that error shows up:

[image]

[image]

Is weird but if i use an await when asigning the user id to the method of generate token , and then i trigger all the process, then the login isn't successful, and console loggin the catch of that error brings me the token in fact:

```
......
 const tokenGenerated =await  generateToken(userInDb.id);//adding an await

    // console.log(tokenGenerated,"controller token");
    // console.log(userInDb);
    response.status(200).json({
      ok: true,
      message: "User Logged",
      tokenGenerated,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error,"Error");//loggin the error in the catch
    response.status(500).json({
      ok: false,
      message: "Some error happened in login",
    });
  }
```

[image]

and in postman the not successful login
[image]

Would be amazing any help on this . Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `generateToken` is async function. Add `await` while calling the function.

Comment: if i add an await , it does redirect me to the catch , exposing an error

Comment: What does the catch error say?

Comment: the error brings the token  when i console it

Comment: But, none of your catch blocks return the token. The only response that does is a `200` response. Can you post the log?

Comment: i modified my issue, there the image and the log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of the callback in `new Promise()` within `generateToken`  is wrong

You are using

```
return new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
...
});
```

but the correct one is

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
...
});
```

ie, you switched the `resolve` and `reject` parameter. Thus when in your method you try to call `resolve(generatedToken);` you are actually rejecting your promise with an error of the generated token.